# laravel project, storing object instead of string

Tags: php

This is my controller where I used to add URLs into the database. the main idea is to send HTTP request and based on the response to save it to the database.when a URL is added, it has to be saved to the database.

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','website_url','email','slack_channel','check_frequency','alert_frequency','speed_frequency','active'];

    public function statuses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withPivot('values')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function status($s_type)
    {
        $o_health_status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();
        $o_speed_status = Status::where('name', 'speed')->first();

        if ($s_type === 'health'){

            $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_health_status->id)
            ->select('values')->orderBy('created_at','ASC')->first();

            if($o_response === null){
                return 'unsigned';
            }
            $o_response = $o_response->values;
            return $o_response;         
        }else{

            $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_speed_status->id)
            ->select('values')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
            if($o_response === null){
                return 'unsigned';
            }

            $o_response = $o_response->values;
            return $o_response;
        }
    }
```

and more over my store method in my model looks like this

```
    else {
        // store
        $notification = new Notification();
        $statusType = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();
        $statusTypeSpeed = Status::where('name', 'speed')->first();
        // trial

        $notification->website_url       = $request->get('website_url');
        $notification->email             = $request->get('email');
        $notification->slack_channel     = $request->get('slack_channel');
        $notification->check_frequency   = $request->get('check_frequency');
        $notification->alert_frequency   = $request->get('alert_frequency');
        $notification->speed_frequency   = $request->get('speed_frequency');

        $notification->active = ($request->has('active') && $request->get('active') === 'on') ? 0 : 1;

        $notification->save();
        $notification->statuses()->attach($statusType,['values'=>$statusTypeSpeed]);

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created notification!');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
}
```

I was expecting to store unsinged in both the second and third columns of my database but insted the second column is storing an object

```
    else {
        // store
        $notification = new Notification();
        $statusType = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();
        $statusTypeSpeed = Status::where('name', 'speed')->first();

        // trial
        $notification->website_url       = $request->get('website_url');
        $notification->email             = $request->get('email');
        $notification->slack_channel     = $request- >get('slack_channel');
        $notification->check_frequency   = $request->get('check_frequency');
        $notification->alert_frequency   = $request->get('alert_frequency');
        $notification->speed_frequency   = $request->get('speed_frequency');
        $notification->active = ($request->has('active') && $request->get('active') === 'on') ? 0 : 1;
        $notification->save();
        $notification->statuses()->attach($statusType,['values'=>$statusTypeSpeed]);

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created notification!');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

I was expecting the unsigned on the first and second columns of my database. in stead on the first comumn i am storing object.

1 column

```
{"id":1,"name":"health"} 2016-11-14 13:07:18
```

2 column

```
unsigned-2016-11-14 13:07:18
```

Comment: i expected to get a string "unsinged" on the second and third column of my DB, instead I got the following